# Is the square root of a symmetric positive definite matrix also symmetric?

Tags: matrices

The inverse of a SPD matrix is also symmetric.
But what about the square root? Intuitively, I would say yes. But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Yes, it is. Infact it is true for any self-adjoint positive definite operator in Hilbert space by the spectral theorem.

Comment: An SPD matrix has a unique square root. Think of it as an analog of the scalar case: each positive real number has a positive square root.

Comment: Consider the square roots of the $2x2$ identity $I_{2}$ found by putting $\pm 1$ along the diagonal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each PSD matrix certainly **has** a symmetric square root.  In fact, PSD matrices have a unique PSD square root.  However, not every square root of a PSD matrix is symmetric.

For example, the $2 \times 2$ zero matrix is PSD, but
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
Is not symmetric, even though $A^2$ is PSD.

**EDIT:** If, like Pavel (below) you need some positivity in your PSD matrix, you should consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}
$$

Comment: I would almost certainly think that the zero matrix is only semi-definite :)

Comment: So you meant PSD instead of SPD, now I got it.

Comment: @PavelJiranek Whoops! I knew something seemed off.

Comment: LOL. You guys have taken too much alphabet soup.

Answer (score 3):

There exist both positive-definite and non-positive-definite square roots for a Symmetric Positive-Definite matrix.

If A is SPD, then A can be represented as UDU* for some unitary matrix U and diagonal matrix D, with the eigenvalues represented in D, and all eigenvalues positive.

If I let R = sqrt(D) then I claim that URU* is a square root of A.  Notice:

`(URU*)^2 = URU*URU* = URRU = UDU = A`

To find a particular square root, I only need to worry about finding square roots of the eigenvalues of D.  There will be both positive and negative values for the square roots and sometimes a mix of both.

However, a matrix is positive-definite only when all the eigenvalues are positive.  You can indeed find a square root with all positive values, but you can also find some with both positive and negative eigenvalues.