# Is square-root of a real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix real as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $A$, will there be a root $R$ which is real symmetric positive semi-definite as well? Can you comment on it's uniqueness? It will be nice if you can give proofs as well.

Comment: @M.Vinay updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Also, related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793777/is-the-square-root-of-a-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-also-symmetric

Comment: The title says square, the body says root... Which is it? To answer the question in the title, of course the square of a real matrix is still a real matrix.

Comment: One proof is given [here](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~foucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect7.pdf)

Comment: @Rahul sorry for the typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the real Schur factorization of $A$, i.e. $A = UTU'$, where $U$ is orthogonal and $T$ is diagonal matrix with nonnegative elements $d_i$. Let
$$A_{1/2} = UT_{1/2}U'$$
where $T_{1/2}$ is a real diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $d_i^{1/2}$. Then
$$A_{1/2}A_{1/2} = UT_{1/2}U'UT_{1/2}U' = UT_{1/2}T_{1/2}U' = UTU' = A$$
hence, $A_{1/2}$ is a square root of $A$. Since all elements of $T_{1/2}$ are nonnegative, the matrix $A_{1/2}$ is real symmetric and semi positive definite (positive definite if $A$ is positive definite).

The square root of $A$ is not unique, since $-A_{1/2}$ is also the square root of $A$.

Comment: but, is the square root real?

Comment: @dineshdileep yes, I edited my answer to make it more clear, that $A_{1/2}$ is real.

Comment: sorry to bother more, but why is schur factorization real? I thought that $U$ can be complex in schur factorization.

Comment: @dineshdileep If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries then $A$ can be factored into a product $UT U^T$ where $U$ is a real orthogonal
matrix and $T$ is a real quasi upper triangular matrix. If $A$ is symmetric, then $T$ is diagonal. On wiki only complex Schur factorization is mentioned. Real factorization is described for example [here](http://kurser.lobner.dk/LinAlg/Tilf%C2%B0jelser%20til%20Leons%20bog/RealSchur.pdf),

Comment: that makes sense!. +1